# Is it a good practice to extend NSError

Tags: ios, objective-c, nserror

Sorry for asking this question. I know in java we are extending Exception class for custom exceptions. But I don't see any scenarios for that in objective c.

So my question, Is it a good practice to extend NSError and introducing custom errors? If so when we should extend NSError class. I checked documentation for this too. But I can't see overriding notes for NSError.

Comment: I don't see the need as `NSError` provides a domain property which you can set to whatever domain-specific value.  What value are you thinking of adding with a `NSError` subclass?

Comment: I was thinking the same as well. But lets say scenarios like exposing some more informations about the error. May be some domain specific details.

Comment: Again, already covered by `NSError` by adding entries to the `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: I see. So there is no concept like extending NSError. Thanks!

Comment: In general, Cocoa does much more with class composition and instance configuration and less of the "subclass everything" design pattern you find in Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never seen it done and that's because `NSError` is already very versatile.  It allows the type of error to be defined by setting the `domain` and `code` properties and allows arbitrary additional information to be attached within the `userInfo` dictionary.

So, no, it's not good practice.

Comment: For more info check out [NSError article](http://nshipster.com/nserror/) by NSHipster. So far the only place I've seen that has a huge list of possible NSErrors in one place.

Comment: It is ok to subclass as it is written in an Apple documentation.

Answer (score 15):

While I agree that you shouldn't subclass `NSError`, it is very useful to put categories on it, and I do this regularly. For example, say your system often posts errors that come from some JSON block. I'd find it very convenient to create a category like:

```
@interface NSError (MyErrors)
// Construct an NSError from data in JSON.
// Include full JSON response in the userInfo
+ (NSError *)myErrorWithJSON:(JSON *)json;

// Parse the text out of the user info
- (NSString *)myErrorMessage;

// The full JSON error block as a string
- (NSString *)myErrorJSON;

// BOOLs can be helpful sometimes, or you could return an enum for use in a switch.
- (BOOL)myIsNetworkError;
- (BOOL)myIsAuthError;
@end
```

I often write little helpers to construct `NSError` more simply, construct the userinfo the way I want, and the pull data back out of the userinfo without callers needing to know its internal representation. I find this to be a very good form of data-hiding, and encourages the use of more descriptive messages.

Similarly, even for smaller projects, I often create a `+myErrorWithCode:localizedDescription:` category method. I know my domain, so I usually don't need to pass that, and this makes it a lot easier to set the `NSLocalizedDescription` key in the user info. Again, this encourages better errors by making them easier to create, and makes it easier to change the implementation details of your error handling.

Answer (score 7):

In the documentation is written that it is ok to subclass:

> Applications may choose to create subclasses of NSError, for example,
>   to provide better localized error strings by overriding
>   localizedDescription.

In my case I am working with **OSStatus** which is **Int32**. NSError constructor supports only **Int**. So I need to subclass it to support **OSSStatus**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad idea to extend NSError.
I also have made a category on `NSError` for my own use. I would like to share it with you.

**(1) Make a `strings` file to define all the error codes:**

```
/* Following are general error messgaes those we can show to user
   regarding to Internet connection and request. You can add more
   codes. */

"-1001" = "Connection time out";
"-1003" = "Cannot find Host";
"-1004" = "Cannot connect to Host";
"-1005" = "Server is temporarily down";
"-1009" = "The Internet connection appears to be offline";
"-1012" = "Authentication failed";
"2000"   = "This is a custom error message"; // custom created error code

/* Always describe unknow error with whatever you want in
   except case (i.e. except error codes). If not mentioned
   the following line, still you will get message "Unknown error" */
"Unknown error" = "Network error occured";
```

**(2) Make a category on NSError, let say "NSError+ErrorInfo":**

```
@interface NSError (ErrorInfo)

-(NSString *)userDescription;

@end
```

**(3) Define it:**

```
#define ERROR_KEY(code)                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",code]
#define ERROR_LOCALIZED_DESCRIPTION(code)  NSLocalizedStringFromTable(ERROR_KEY(code),@"Errors",nil)

@implementation NSError (ErrorInfo)

-(NSString *)userDescription
{
    NSString *errorDescrption = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(ERROR_KEY(self.code),@"Errors",nil);

    if (!errorDescrption || [errorDescrption isEqual:ERROR_KEY(self.code)]){
        return NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Unknown error",@"Errors",nil);;
    }

    else{
        return ERROR_LOCALIZED_DESCRIPTION(self.code);
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

**(4) Make use of it:**

```
NSError *yourError; // This can be any NSError object you get
yourError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"yourDomain" code:2000 userInfo:details]; // Just for test
NSLog(@"%@",[yourError userDescription]);
```